# PHP json_decode function just work UTF-8 encoded strings?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, json

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) you can read that `json_decode` function

> only works with UTF-8 encoded strings.

Then why the following lines result in different output?

```
echo utf8_decode('1ñ2'), "\n";
echo json_decode('"' . '1ñ2' . '"'), "\n";
```

'ñ' character is not a valid UTF-8 character, even so `json_decode` doesn't complain when that character is passed into the string it must decode.

Comment: "ñ" actually is a valid UTF-8 character. I didn't get whats the problem here, as those functions do different things. This is the expected result for each one.

Comment: "ñ" must be represented as a multibyte character cos it have the highest significant bit set, so the UTF-8 character is 'ñ2', and that is not a valid UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

That's because these both function are doing complete different stuff. While `json_decode()` keeps the character encoding as is (utf-8) and just parses json data into a PHP structure, [`utf8_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) transforms the character encoding to ISO-8859-1. But ISO-8859-1 don't knows about that special multibyte chars.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agreed with the fact that those functions do a completely different stuff, I read the doc ;) My point is that the string '1ñ2' is not a valid UTF-8 string (the multibyte char 'ñ2' is not a valid UTF-8 character), that is why `utf8_decode` "complain", so why `json_decode()` don't complain? Seem to me that `json_decode()` don't require that the string be UTF-8 at all as the doc said, may be just need that JSON critical characters be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: if not utf-8, what type of encoding is it? AFAIK utf-8 defines any existing char on world (and more :) ..

Comment: LOL This is trivial, anyway I will clear it: "valid UTF-8 string" = "correctly encoded UTF-8 string" and '1ñ2' is not a correctly encoded UTF-8 string, that is why `utf8_decode` function complain. '1ñ2' = '00110001 11000011 00110001' and those last 16bits don't form a valid multibyte UTF-8 character, cos the last 8bit must start with '10'. PS: I'm not an Unicode expert.

Comment: need to debug this. currently very lazy :)